# Initialize sbyte** in C# unsafe context

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe

How can sbyte** be initialized in C# unsafe context?

I need

```
sbyte** parameters;
```

to be filled with three strings: "first", "second", "third".

Comment: How about `sbyte*[] parameters = { "first", "second", "third" };`.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please clarify your intentions? Do you mean that you want an array of `sbyte**`, for example, through a function prototype of `void foo(params sbyte** arrOfSByte);`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Cannot convert expression of type 'string' to type 'sbyte*'

Comment: @freedompease: I want to call a method that takes sbyte** argv as an argument.

Comment: Sorry, first off it should have been `sbyte[][] parameters = { "abc", "def" };` but that still doesn't accept the string literal as a byte array...

Comment: Ah, got it, you need `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`, but that'll get you `byte`, not `sbyte`. Is that OK?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks for the tip, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution using `byte**`. This should be compatible with `sbyte**` as the encoding used is ASCII and only has values to 127.

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
  fixed (byte* arg0 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0]), 
               arg1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[1]), 
               arg2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[2]))
  {
    byte*[] arr = { arg0, arg1, arg2 };

    fixed (byte** argv = arr)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```